# MS Access average after subtracting

Tags: sql, ms-access

how can I subtract these two columns and then find their average grouping by `col3`:

```
col1,     col2,     col3
02:00:00, 04:00:00, 4
02:00:00, 05:00:00, 3
```

**i want the result in this format: `Hours:Minutes:Seconds`**

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT col3, Format(Avg([col2]-[col1]),"hh:mm:ss") AS TimeDiff
FROM Table1
GROUP BY col3;
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the difference of col1 and col2 in seconds

```
select col3, datediff("s", col2, col1) as diff_n_seconds from mytable
```

and save that as a query

Then build a group-by query on the first query. Put an average on it

```
select avg(diff_n_seconds), col3 from myquery groupby col3
```

and convert the avg back to a time format using the format function - e.g.,

```
Format(int([FieldName]/3600),"00") & ":" & Format(Int(([FieldName]-(Int([FieldName]/3600)*3600))/60),"00") & ":" & Format((([FieldName] Mod 60)),"00")
```

Reply With Quote

(you could do this in the same query, or build a new one off of the previous one)

Comment: can it be done using one query .. i tried ur solution but when i try to build the Group by it says there is an error in FROM statement .. i want it to be in this format: Hours:Minutes:Seconds